# C++ - Template Specialization & Partial Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, class-template

I have been looking all over the internet and stackoverflow for a concrete answer but I can't seem to find one. I have to create a generic class and then implement specific functions. My specific instructions were: You need to make use of Template Expression Parameters and Template Class Specialization and Partial Specialization.

I have a template class:

```
template <class T, int x, int y>
class Z {
    T **array[x][y];
    public:
         Z();
         void print();
         //and other methods
};
```

I need to:

1) Only Z's where x= 2 and y = 2 need to have a public method void J()

2) For char Z's of x = 2 and y= 2 J will do something; for everything else it does something else

3) For only Z's where T is char will the array be initialized to some value. For everything else it's 0

Naturally, this works:

```
template<class T, int x, int y>
Z<T,x,y>::Z<T,x,y>() { //initialize to 0 }
```

But this doesn't:

```
template<int x, int y>
Z<char,x,y>::Z<char,x,y>() { //initialize to something}
```

And likewise (assume J exists) this does not work:

```
template <class T>
void Z<T,2,2>::J() { //something }
```

My question is:

Is there any simple method for implementing the above items? I need to keep all the other methods in Z. Giving a hint or pointing in the right direction (maybe I missed a question since there are a lot) would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Which errors do you have ? What is `J` ? It is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: J is some function. What I need to do is listed 1,2,3. My errors are (next comments):

Comment: For Z<char,x,y>::Z<char,x,y>() { //stuff } : "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token" and "expected `;' before '<' token "

Comment: And assuming J exists: void Z<char,x,y>::J() {//stuff} gives the errors: "invalid use of undefined type `class Z<char, x, y>'" and "template definition of non-template `void Z<char, x, y>::J()' "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want to define only some functions of some specializations : if `print()` does not change between the `char` specialization and the general case, it seems that you don't want to redefine it.

```
// What you want to do (illegal in C++)
template<int,typename T>
struct Z
{
    T myValue;
    Z();
    void print() { /* ... */ }
};

template<int i, typename T>
Z<i,T>::Z() { /* ... */ }

template<int i>
Z<i,char>::Z() { /* ... */ }
```

However, it does not work like this. **Partial or full specializations of class have almost nothing in common, except 'prototype' of template parameters**:

```
// The two following types have only two things related: the template parameter is an int,
// and the second type is a full specialization of the first. There are no relations between
// the content of these 2 types.
template<int> struct A {};
template<> struct A<42> { void work(); };
```

You have to declare and define each (partial) specialization:

```
// Fixed example
template<int,typename T>
struct Z
{
    T myValue;
    Z();
    void print() { /* ... */ }
};
template<int i, typename T>
Z<i,T>::Z() { /* ... */ }

// Specialization for <all-ints,char>
template<int i>
struct Z<i,char>
{
    char myValue;
    char othervalue;
    Z();
    void print() { /* Same code than for the general case */ }
};

template<int i>
Z<i,char>::Z() { /* ... */ }
```

The only way to escape the code duplication is by using inheritance of *traits*:

```
// Example with the print function
template<typename T>
struct print_helper
{
    void print() { /* ... */ }
};

// Fixed example
template<int,typename T>
struct Z : public print_helper<T>
{
    T myValue;
    Z();
};
template<int i, typename T>
Z<i,T>::Z() { /* ... */ }

// Specialization for <all-ints,char>
template<int i>
struct Z<i,char> : public print_helper<char>
{
    char myValue;
    char othervalue;
    Z();
};

template<int i>
Z<i,char>::Z() { /* ... */ }
```

You cannot do what you want without duplication for the moment (*the feature removing code duplication is `static if` and has been proposed for the next C++ standard, see [n3322](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3322.pdf) and [n3329](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3329.pdf)).*

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But I wanted to know if there was a simpler way to do this without duplicating code all over the place. (Because obviously that's a very bad thing)

Comment: That isn't inheritance since you still have to duplicate code everywhere in your solution (same as before). In any case, I'll try to get some inheritance working.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at this course http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-5-of-n

While this is not possible that you define partial specialization for function templates, you can define partial specialization for class or struct template.

```
template<typename T> struct helper {
    static void doThingy(){}
};

template<typename X> struct helper<X*> {
    static void doThingy(){}
};

Helper(double*)::doThingy();
```

In this example, you want to specialize behavior in doThingy() only when the type in template is a pointer type. You cannot use overload of method doThingy() in this case. This is because you cannot overload a function with no arguments. But you can have partial specialization of the struct helper. In specialized template, you implemented wished behavior for the doThingy().