# Template partial specialization problems

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, partial-specialization

I am trying to write a size and type generic vector class for math programming. I am having problems with partial specialization.

The problem occurs when I try to specialize a member method of my vector class for given size.

I can provide a simple example:

```
template <size_t Size, typename Type>
class TestVector
{
public:
    inline TestVector (){}
    TestVector cross (TestVector const& other) const;
};

template < typename Type >
inline TestVector< 3, Type > TestVector< 3, Type >::cross (TestVector< 3, Type > const& other) const
{
    return TestVector< 3, Type >();
}

void test ()
{
    TestVector< 3, double > vec0;
    TestVector< 3, double > vec1;
    vec0.cross(vec1);
}
```

When trying to compile this simple example I get a compilation error stating the 'cross' specialization does not match an existing declaration:

```
error C2244: 'TestVector<Size,Type>::cross' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
see declaration of 'TestVector<Size,Type>::cross'
definition
    'TestVector<3,Type> TestVector<3,Type>::cross(const TestVector<3,Type> &) const'
    existing declarations
    'TestVector<Size,Type> TestVector<Size,Type>::cross(const TestVector<Size,Type> &) const'
```

I have tried to declare cross as a template:

```
template <size_t Size, typename Type>
class TestVector
{
public:
    inline TestVector (){}

    template < class OtherVec >
    TestVector cross (OtherVec const& other) const;
};

template < typename Type >
TestVector< 3, Type > TestVector< 3, Type >::cross< TestVector< 3, Type > > (TestVector< 3, Type > const& other) const
{
    return TestVector< 3, Type >();
}
```

This version passes compilation but fails at link-time:

```
 unresolved external symbol "public: class TestVector<3,double> __thiscall TestVector<3,double>::cross<class TestVector<3,double> >(class TestVector<3,double> const &)const
```

What am I missing here ?
Thanks,
Florent

Comment: One problem is that you're not partially specializing the `class` but some function inside it, where your `class` here is what is *templated*, so a partial specialization should be another class template.

Comment: @TonyTheLion Thanks, so you say I should specialize the full Vector class ? My problem with that is that it would require me to rewrite the full class (it contains a lot of methods, not only cross)

Comment: Question already asked. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444615/c-template-specialization-partial-specialization/13444841#13444841

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to define `cross` as a "functor" (that is, a class with an `operator()`).

```
template<size_t S, typename T>
class Vec {
  // ... stuff
  friend struct Cross<S, T>;
  Vec<S, T> cross(const Vec<S, T>& other) {
    return Cross<S, T>()(*this, other);
  }
  // ... more stuff
};


template<size_t S, typename T> struct Cross {
  Vec<S, T> operator() (const Vec<S, T>& a, const Vec<S, T>& b) {
    // general definition
  }
};

// Partial specialization
template<typename T> struct Cross<3, T> {
  vec<3, T> operator() (const Vec<3, T>& a, const Vec<3, T>& b) {
    // specialize definition
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the option I went for. But there is a small error in provided code, the operator () takes two arguments ;)

Comment: @F.L. Oops, sorry. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partially specialize a method. You can overload under certain conditions. Here, you could go with a partial specialization of your class

```
template <size_t Size, typename Type> class TestVector
{
public:
    inline TestVector (){}
    TestVector cross (TestVector const& other) const;
};
```

with definition for the general behavior:

```
TestVector<size_t Size, typename Type>::cross (TestVector const& other) const {
     // general
}
```

and a specialized template that will enable you to define specific behavior for the case int is 3

```
template <typename Type> class TestVector<3, Type>
{
public:
    inline TestVector (){}
    TestVector cross (TestVector const& other) const;
};
```

with definition for the custom behavior:

```
TestVector<typename Type>::cross (TestVector const& other) const {
     // custom
}
```